# Asp.net AjaxFileUpload Change Button Text

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm using ajaxfileupload but I can't change the control buttons text. I need to convert Turkish lang. How can I do that?

look that

[image]

example "Drop files here" must be "Dosyaları buraya sürükleyin"

Comment: how about searching for the text and replacing it?

Comment: Whoa! Something awful happened to your Chrome (or whatever's mimicking it), you know?

Comment: MUG4N - I'll search but where?

GrantThomas - It's comodo dragon. Same with chrome.

Answer (score 2):

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {
        AjaxFileUpload_change_text();
    });

    function AjaxFileUpload_change_text() {

        document.getElementsByClassName('ajax__fileupload_selectFileButton')[0].innerHTML = "Abrir";
        document.getElementsByClassName('ajax__fileupload_dropzone')[0].innerHTML = "Arrastre archivo aquí";
        document.getElementsByClassName('ajax__fileupload_uploadbutton')[0].innerHTML = "Subir";
        document.getElementById("ctl00_MainContent_AjaxFileUpload1_FileStatusContainer").innerHTML = "Seleccione archivo(s) a subir.";

        Sys.Extended.UI.Resources.AjaxFileUpload_Pending = "Pendiente";
        Sys.Extended.UI.Resources.AjaxFileUpload_Pending = "Pendiente";
        Sys.Extended.UI.Resources.AjaxFileUpload_Remove = "Quitar";
        Sys.Extended.UI.Resources.AjaxFileUpload_Upload = "Subir";
        Sys.Extended.UI.Resources.AjaxFileUpload_Uploaded = "Subido";
        Sys.Extended.UI.Resources.AjaxFileUpload_UploadedPercentage = "{0} %";
        Sys.Extended.UI.Resources.AjaxFileUpload_Uploading = "Subiendo";
        Sys.Extended.UI.Resources.AjaxFileUpload_FileInQueue = "{0} archivos(s) en espera.";
        Sys.Extended.UI.Resources.AjaxFileUpload_AllFilesUploaded = "Completado.";
        Sys.Extended.UI.Resources.AjaxFileUpload_FileList = "Archivos subidos:";
        Sys.Extended.UI.Resources.AjaxFileUpload_Cancelling = "Cancelando...";
        Sys.Extended.UI.Resources.AjaxFileUpload_UploadError = "error";
        Sys.Extended.UI.Resources.AjaxFileUpload_CancellingUpload = "Cancelando...";
        Sys.Extended.UI.Resources.AjaxFileUpload_UploadingInputFile = "Subiendo: {0}.";
        Sys.Extended.UI.Resources.AjaxFileUpload_Cancel = "Cancelar";
        Sys.Extended.UI.Resources.AjaxFileUpload_Canceled = "cancelado";
        Sys.Extended.UI.Resources.AjaxFileUpload_UploadCanceled = "Subida cancelada";
        Sys.Extended.UI.Resources.AjaxFileUpload_DefaultError = "Error";
        Sys.Extended.UI.Resources.AjaxFileUpload_UploadingHtml5File = "Subiendo: {0}, peso: {1} bytes.";
        Sys.Extended.UI.Resources.AjaxFileUpload_error = "error";
    }

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use controls Localization for that purpose?

> With the localization support, the controls now use strings translated into that locale’s language. So if your website has the culture-sensitive settings turned on, then the Toolkit controls will work out of the box without any extra effort on the part of the website author to build separately for other languages

[Reference](http://ajaxcontroltoolkit.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Localization)